# how to acess string stored inside for loop outside the for loop in java

Tags: java

What i want is i need to access the string which is stored  in the for loop to be accessed outside the for loop.since i need it for another operation.I tried by creating another  string outside the loop and assign the same string variable to it,but its not possible.Is any way through which i can achieve it?

```
for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
     System.out.println(nodeList.item(index).getTextContent());
      String excelpath1 = nodeList.item(index).getTextContent();

    }
```

Now here i want to access `excelpath1` outside the for loop.please suggest me someway through which i can achieve it.

Comment: I tried by creating another string outside the loop and assign the same string variable to it,but its not possible. this scenario is not possible or you couldn't do it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it outside the loop.

```
String excelpath1 = null;
for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
     System.out.println(nodeList.item(index).getTextContent());
      excelpath1 = nodeList.item(index).getTextContent();
    }
System.out.println("excelpath1 is " + excelpath1);
```

Comment: I don't want o validate  `excelpath1` since my path in the back end may change,so each time changing the path just to validate it with that if statement will be tedious task.that is why i just need the string

Comment: I'm actually not validating it, Just wanted to show you that it could be used outside.

Comment: here you can get only last value.

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it is impossible due to the scope of variable visiblity, since it only localy visible and existing in the loop

You could declare the String before the loop, but i don´t know if looping over multiple entries and saving the value in a single String would be usefull.

```
String excelpath1;
for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
     System.out.println(nodeList.item(index).getTextContent());
     excelpath1 = nodeList.item(index).getTextContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare String outside for loop as below

```
String excelpath1 = null;
```

And initialize this inside for loop. You can use this value outside for loop too.

Each time it stores with latest value. That means the value which is stored before existing the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` and avoid `String` object creation inside `for loop`.

```
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
             sb.append(nodeList.item(index).getTextContent());
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
```